# How to run a jar example(word count) on Docker with Hadoop and Spark installed?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop and Spark on Docker. Now, I want to verify that the installations are succesfully done, through a simple jar of a word count example. But I do not know how to do it. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Hadoop. Spark can run wordcount on plain-text local files

You can use `spark-shell` rather than any JAR. Run the code from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html), but use `file:///` path

```scala
text_file = sc.textFile("file:///some_local_folder")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.saveAsTextFile("file:///tmp/results")
```